# How to set the max and min limit year for moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I do use `moment.js` to parse the date. So far, it does parse the date valid, but after reading the documentation I didn't find how to set some logical checks. What I have now:

```
var death_day_moment = moment(death, ["DD-MM-YYYY"]);

var dmy = death_day_moment.invalidAt();
switch(dmy) {
   case 0:
    alert("The year is wrong");
    $("#JZpVcQRKECR-CupAzN1n4xv-val").val(""); 
    return;

   case 1:
    alert("The month is wrong);
    $("#JZpVcQRKECR-CupAzN1n4xv-val").val(""); 
    return;

   case 2:
    alert("The day is wrong");
    $("#JZpVcQRKECR-CupAzN1n4xv-val").val(""); 
    return;
}
```

It does work, overall, it does validate if its date or no. But I want to limit the date to current max date (so they cant put the future, tomorrow's date) for example. How would one do it?

Examples, lest say today is 23--05-2017 (current date):

Inputs:

01-01-2017 -- Correct

01-12-2016 -- Incorrect as its from previous year

01-06-2017 -- Incorrect as its the future date.

02-02-2017 -- Correct

Edit1: I have moment.js version 2.5

Comment: Do you need to check if the input date is between start of the year and today?

Comment: try using http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Comment: @VincenzoC, I want to be able to give it a range. That was just one of the examples. I want it to be configurable, so I can give a range of valid date and it does gets validated between those dates in addition to what it does.

Comment: Maybe [`isBetween`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/) could help you.

Comment: @VincenzoC, isBetween seems like a solution. You may want to post it so I'll aceept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`isBetween`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/)

> Check if a moment is between two other moments, optionally looking at unit scale (minutes, hours, days, etc). The match is exclusive.

But you have to update to moment 2.9.0+